# How to use cmd.exe commands in QProcess

Tags: qt, qt5, qprocess

I try to run command type  in Windows Command Prompt, but process doesn't start. If I try to use this command straigth througt the Command Prompt, it works.
This is the code:

```
void MainWindow::firmware()
{
    QProcess *proc = new QProcess(this);
    QString dir("C:/Qtstatic/Examples/My/build-RBoxReader-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug");
    proc->setWorkingDirectory(dir);
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    QString msg = "Current dir: %1";
    msg = msg.arg(proc->workingDirectory());
    msgBox.setText(msg);
    msgBox.exec();
    QString command("type");
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "my_file.txt";
    proc->start(command, arguments);
    if(!proc->waitForStarted()) {
        QMessageBox msgBox1;
        QString msg1 = "Process state: %1";
        msg1 = msg1.arg(proc->state());
          msgBox1.setText(msg1);
          msgBox1.exec();
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        QString msg = "Process didn't start";
          msgBox.setText(msg);
          msgBox.exec();
          return;
    }
    msg = "Process state: %1";
    msg = msg.arg(proc->state());
      msgBox.setText(msg);
      msgBox.exec();
    proc->waitForFinished (-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that nowhere in your code do I see `"cmd.exe"`, I fail to understand what you expected. There's no `type.exe` on your system. You have to actually run `cmd.exe` yourself, and pass `type` as an argument to it:

You'll want something like:

```
QString command = QStringLiteral("cmd.exe");
QStringList arguments{QStringLiteral("/K"),
                      QStringLiteral("type"),
                      QStringLiteral("my_file.txt")};
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. I thought, that QProcess appeal straight to cmd like system(). Excuse me for one more question, but why `proc->start("fsutil file createnew m_file.txt  1000");` work without running cmd.exe? I tried this command and file was made.

Comment: @CaboomBom `fsutil` is an executable that you can find. `type` is not. That's the difference. `cmd.exe` is mudding the waters by mixing the internal and external commands so at no point you can be quite sure what's what. It is IMHO the biggest problem with typical command shells. Internal and external commands have such major performance differences that hiding this borders on the absurd. It always bothered me, and millions of beginners get tripped up on this. Not good.